# install influx database v2 on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04

Not a lot of wisdom here on Linux or databases but on home test bench I am trying to install influx v2 on an Ubuntu Desktop 20.04 with this tutorial where [I can get all the way step 8](https://www.cyberithub.com/how-to-install-influxdb2-on-ubuntu-20-04-lts-step-by-step/#:%7E:text=09T21%3A24%3A22Z-,step%208%3A%20start%20influxdb%20service,-By%20default%2C%20influxdb).

Looks like this on my end checking the status:

```
ben@ben-HP-ProBook-6550b:~/Desktop$ systemctl status influxdb
● influxdb.service - InfluxDB is an open-source, distributed, time series database
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/influxdb.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Mon 2022-09-12 15:14:37 CDT; 4 days ago
       Docs: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/
   Main PID: 3880 (influxd)
      Tasks: 15 (limit: 4369)
     Memory: 78.7M
     CGroup: /system.slice/influxdb.service
             └─3880 /usr/bin/influxd -config /etc/influxdb/influxdb.conf

Sep 17 11:06:49 ben-HP-ProBook-6550b influxd-systemd-start.sh[3880]: [httpd] 127.0.0.1 - admin [17/Sep/2022:11:06:49 -0500] "POST /query?chunked=true&db=me>Sep 17 11:10:14 ben-HP-ProBook-6550b influxd-systemd-start.sh[3880]: ts=2022-09-17T16:10:14.914231Z lvl=info msg="Executing query" log_id=0ctqH80G000 servi>Sep 17 11:10:15 ben-HP-ProBook-6550b influxd-systemd-start.sh[3880]: [httpd] 127.0.0.1 - admin [17/Sep/2022:11:10:14 -0500] "POST /query?chunked=true&db=me>Sep 17 11:10:30 ben-HP-ProBook-6550b influxd-systemd-start.sh[3880]: ts=2022-09-17T16:10:30.704715Z lvl=info msg="Executing query" log_id=0ctqH80G000 servi>Sep 17 11:10:30 ben-HP-ProBook-6550b influxd-systemd-start.sh[3880]: [httpd] 127.0.0.1 - admin [17/Sep/2022:11:10:30 -0500] "POST /query?db=&epoch=ns&q=SHO>Sep 17 11:12:10 ben-HP-ProBook-6550b influxd-systemd-start.sh[3880]: ts=2022-09-17T16:12:10.558516Z lvl=info msg="Executing query" log_id=0ctqH80G000 servi>Sep 17 11:12:10 ben-HP-ProBook-6550b influxd-systemd-start.sh[3880]: [httpd] 127.0.0.1 - admin [17/Sep/2022:11:12:10 -0500] "POST /query?chunked=true&db=BE>Sep 17 11:14:36 ben-HP-ProBook-6550b influxd-systemd-start.sh[3880]: ts=2022-09-17T16:14:36.276930Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (start)" >Sep 17 11:14:36 ben-HP-ProBook-6550b influxd-systemd-start.sh[3880]: ts=2022-09-17T16:14:36.277031Z lvl=info msg="Retention policy deletion check (end)" lo>Sep 17 11:22:55 ben-HP-ProBook-6550b influxd-systemd-start.sh[3880]: [httpd] 127.0.0.1 - admin [17/Sep/2022:11:22:55 -0500] "POST /query?chunked=true&db=BE>
```

If I do step 9 in the tutorial I get this authentication prompt:

```
ben@ben-HP-ProBook-6550b:~/Desktop$ systemctl enable influxdb
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ===
Authentication is required to manage system service or unit files.
Authenticating as: ben,,, (ben)
Password:
```

And when I type in my username password for `ben` and type it in twice:

```
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon ===
Authentication is required to reload the systemd state.
Authenticating as: ben,,, (ben)
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
```

And then assuming I can get to the next step in the tutorial step 10 `influx setup` a few more auth steps I get a 404 returned on the command prompt. Any ideas to try?

```
$ systemctl enable influxdb
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.manage-unit-files ===
Authentication is required to manage system service or unit files.
Authenticating as: ben,,, (ben)
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon ===
Authentication is required to reload the systemd state.
Authenticating as: ben,,, (ben)
Password:
==== AUTHENTICATION COMPLETE ===
ben@ben-HP-ProBook-6550b:~/Desktop$ influx setup
Error: failed to check if already set up: 404 Not Found
```

Comment: As 404 is page not found that is a good question to ask the people on the site you are trying to access.

Comment: Thats a web request right? Doesnt make sense to me as I wasnt opening up a web page at all

Comment: If you are not accessing the web what si this line from your question? ==== AUTHENTICATING FOR org.freedesktop.systemd1.reload-daemon === A web site?